# Unique Particle Attribution violation in XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

Why does the following XML give a UPA violation when I validate it?

```
 <xs:element name='Information'>
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice>
    <xs:element ref='ID'/> 
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref='ID'/>     
     <xs:element ref='Name'/>   
    </xs:sequence> 
   </xs:choice>    
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 <xs:element name='ID' type="xs:integer"/> 
 <xs:element name='Name' type="xs:string"/>
```

Does this not simply state that Information is either an integer OR and integer and a string? Where is the dis-ambiguity? Not very well schooled in xml schema so I am probably missing something simple ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ambiguous because when the parser "comes" to the `<ID>` element, it can not select the appropriate content model (here it is `<ID>` alone, or `<ID>` then `<Name>`) without "looking further" in the document.

You need to use a content model defined like that (it is the exact equivalent of the one you want):

```
 <xs:element name='Information'>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref='ID'/> 
      <xs:element ref='Name' minOccurs="0"/>   
    </xs:sequence> 
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just assumed the content model would not be selected until the closing </choice> in the XML was encountered by the parser. In this case it can indeed be fixed by adding that minOccurs. How would I go about the situation where I have either the ID or I have the ID, the Name AND a third element?

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions like this. It's a different question, so open a new question.